# Static Code Analysis - Finding unsanitized/untainted variables

Tags: algorithm, static-analysis

Trying to write this Static Code Analysis Pseudocode/Algorithm.

Have two scenarios:

Safe (Input - $sort - is sanitized/tainted)

```
 <?php
      $sort = htmlentities($_GET['sort']);


      if($sort=="asc")
      {
        echo 'Sorting: '.$sort;
      }elseif($sort=="desc"){
        echo 'Sorting: '.$sort;
      }else{
       echo $sort;
      }
```

Which produces this Tree:

```
{
  "token_name": "C_ROOT",
  "token_group": "C_BLOCK",
  "group": true,
  "body": [
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "sort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_STRING",
        "token": 319,
        "value": "htmlentities",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
        "token_name": "C_FUNCTION_INT",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
              "token": 320,
              "value": "_GET",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "VARIABLES",
              "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
                    "token": 323,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 2,
                    "token_group": "STRINGS",
                    "token_name": "C_STRING"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_IF",
        "token": 327,
        "value": "if",
        "line": 5,
        "token_group": "CONDITIONS",
        "token_name": "C_IF",
        "conditions": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
              "token": 320,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "VARIABLES",
              "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_IS_EQUAL",
              "token": 289,
              "value": "==",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "RELOPERATOR",
              "token_name": "C_IS_EQUAL"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "asc",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ],
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 7,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
                    "token": 323,
                    "value": "Sorting: ",
                    "line": 7,
                    "token_group": "STRINGS",
                    "token_name": "C_STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 7,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_ELSEIF",
        "token": 308,
        "value": "elseif",
        "line": 8,
        "token_group": "CONDITIONS",
        "token_name": "C_ELSEIF",
        "conditions": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
              "token": 320,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "VARIABLES",
              "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_IS_EQUAL",
              "token": 289,
              "value": "==",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "RELOPERATOR",
              "token_name": "C_IS_EQUAL"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "desc",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ],
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 9,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
                    "token": 323,
                    "value": "Sorting: ",
                    "line": 9,
                    "token_group": "STRINGS",
                    "token_name": "C_STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 9,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_ELSE",
        "token": 309,
        "value": "else",
        "line": 10,
        "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
        "token_name": "C_ELSE",
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 11,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 11,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and second one, unsafe, $sort is not sanitized/tainted:

```
<?php
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];


  if($sort=="asc")
  {
    echo 'Sorting: '.$sort;
  }elseif($sort=="desc"){
    echo 'Sorting: '.$sort;
  }else{
   echo $sort;
  }
```

which produces this Tree:

```
{
  "token_name": "C_ROOT",
  "token_group": "C_BLOCK",
  "group": true,
  "body": [
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "sort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "_GET",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_IF",
        "token": 327,
        "value": "if",
        "line": 5,
        "token_group": "CONDITIONS",
        "token_name": "C_IF",
        "conditions": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
              "token": 320,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "VARIABLES",
              "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_IS_EQUAL",
              "token": 289,
              "value": "==",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "RELOPERATOR",
              "token_name": "C_IS_EQUAL"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "asc",
              "line": 5,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ],
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 7,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
                    "token": 323,
                    "value": "Sorting: ",
                    "line": 7,
                    "token_group": "STRINGS",
                    "token_name": "C_STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 7,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_ELSEIF",
        "token": 308,
        "value": "elseif",
        "line": 8,
        "token_group": "CONDITIONS",
        "token_name": "C_ELSEIF",
        "conditions": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
              "token": 320,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "VARIABLES",
              "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_IS_EQUAL",
              "token": 289,
              "value": "==",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "RELOPERATOR",
              "token_name": "C_IS_EQUAL"
            },
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "desc",
              "line": 8,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ],
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 9,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
                    "token": 323,
                    "value": "Sorting: ",
                    "line": 9,
                    "token_group": "STRINGS",
                    "token_name": "C_STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 9,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_ELSE",
        "token": 309,
        "value": "else",
        "line": 10,
        "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
        "token_name": "C_ELSE",
        "body": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_ECHO",
              "token": 328,
              "value": "echo",
              "line": 11,
              "token_group": "FUNCTIONS",
              "token_name": "C_ECHO",
              "args": [
                [
                  {
                    "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
                    "token": 320,
                    "value": "sort",
                    "line": 11,
                    "token_group": "VARIABLES",
                    "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Now I wrote this Pseudocode/Algorithm to find unsanitized/untainted variables:

1. Search for token_group: FUNCTIONS
2. Check if it has args
3. Check in args for token_group: VARIABLES
4. From found args index, take args key “value” and store it
5. Search for token_group ASSIGNMENTS, get next element, if token_group “FUNCTIONS” mark as safe, if token_group “VARIABLES” mark as unsafe
6. Goto Point 1

Is it correct way to do it? Anybody have a different idea/approach how to find those unsanitized/untaitned variables?

As a perfect answer a correct Pseudocode/Algorithm doing this would be the best.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish and exactly what the pseudocode does, but my guess is that it doesn't do what you want.

- Step 4 'stores' a value, but the pseudocode never references it again. More generally, there's no connection between steps 1-4 and step 5.
- The procedure doesn't appear to terminate: if your AST has a FUNCTIONS and an ASSIGNMENTS, then steps 1 and 5 will always succeed, so you'll loop forever.
- The only trigger for marking something safe or unsafe appears to be an assignment statement, but presumably there are safe/unsafe constructs that don't involve assignments. E.g., I imagine that you'd want to consider `echo $_GET['sort'];` as unsafe (but `echo "<p>hi!</p>";` as safe).
- Step 5 appears to treat every function call as safe, and every variable-reference as unsafe, but (depending on what you're trying to accomplish) there are probably counterexamples to both. E.g., `echo trim($_GET['sort']);` involves functions but is unsafe, and `$x = "<p>hi!</p>"; echo $x;` involves variables but is safe.